# dplyr idiom for listing nonzero columns in a row

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a sparse data set in which most values are zero, but some are larger. How can I use `dplyr` to create a column which tells me which column names are not zero?

Take for example,

```
d <- replicate(n = 10,
          expr = sample(x = c(rep(0, 80), runif(20)),
              size = 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% as.data.frame()
names(d) <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

The new column would have rows containing values like `"A,B,J"` if only columns `A`, `B`, and `J` had non-zero values in that particular row.

Comment: I know that for particular rows I can do `sum(d[1,] > 0)`, but I know `sum` doesn't work with `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
 library(dplyr)
 d %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    do(data.frame(., newcol= toString(names(d)[which(.!=0)])))%>% 
    as.data.frame()
```

In `base R`, this could be done using

```
 d$newCol <- apply(d!=0, 1, function(x) toString(names(d)[x]))
```

#### Update

If you need to reorder the names in the string based on the value

```
res <- d %>% 
        rowwise() %>% 
        do(data.frame(., 
         newcol= toString(names(d)[which(.!=0)[order(unlist(.[.!=0]))]])))%>% 
          as.data.frame()
 res$newcol
 #[1] "G, J"          "J, E, H, C, A" "I"             "G"            
 #[5] "D"             "A, B, I"       "C"             "H, J, G"      
 #[9] "F, I"          "H, A"
```

which is the same as

```
  apply(d, 1, function(x) toString(names(which(x!=0)[order(x[x!=0])]))) 
  #[1] "G, J"          "J, E, H, C, A" "I"             "G"            
  #[5] "D"             "A, B, I"       "C"             "H, J, G"      
  #[9] "F, I"          "H, A"   

  d[1:2,]
  #       A    B       C   D        E  F       G         H   I         J
  #1 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0 0.03736996 0.0000000 0 0.6297454
  #2 0.9833502 0 0.7856878 0 0.2405307 0 0.00000000 0.5693827 0 0.1462821
```

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Bonus points if you can suggest a method for reordering the names in the string by how large the number is.

Comment: This looks great! I changed my order to decreasing, but this looks like it works with the example. Now checking it against my data.

Answer (score 3):

This should be much faster than doing the operation by each row:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(d) # or setDT to convert in place

res = as.data.table(which(dt != 0, arr.ind = T))[, paste(names(dt)[col], collapse = ",")
                                                 , by = row]
dt[res$row, newcol := res$V1]
dt
#            A          B         C         D         E         F         G          H I J  newcol
# 1: 0.0000000 0.20367933 0.0000000 0.2839109 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0 0     B,D
# 2: 0.6784289 0.05622799 0.8293551 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0 0   A,B,C
# 3: 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1702222 0.0000000 0.00000000 0 0       F
# 4: 0.9259111 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.9930633 0.00000000 0 0     A,G
# 5: 0.4656185 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.7986647 0.30571672 0 0   A,G,H
# 6: 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.2893704 0.0000000 0.1617378 0.0000000 0.9861549 0.06057971 0 0 C,E,G,H
# 7: 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.1914990 0.0000000 0.5911986 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0 0     C,E
# 8: 0.6359290 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.42127388 0 0     A,H
# 9: 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.4898069 0.00000000 0 0       G
#10: 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0 0      NA
```

Converting the idea to `dplyr`, if you're so inclined, should be straightforward and is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Funny I was in the middle of posting the exact solution. You could probably use `toString` instead of `paste` for more convenient syntax.

Comment: @DavidArenburg sorry :) re `toString` sure - depends on whether OP likes spaces or not (they don't have spaces in the OP, so I went with `paste`)